# Document Names for docusign api downloads

Tags: c#, api, docusignapi

I am using the code below to download documents in an envelope with DocuSign api

Is there a way to get the documents email address?
I can use documentID but that is not a very good filename
Does anyone have suggestions on how to get descriptive filenames
when downloading?

```
MemoryStream docStream = (MemoryStream)envelopesApi.GetDocument(accountId,envelopeId, docsList.EnvelopeDocuments[i].DocumentId);

filePath = "C:\\JohnFolder\\DocuSign\\DownLoads\\" + docsList.EnvelopeDocuments[i].Name + ".pdf";



fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create);
docStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
docStream.CopyTo(fs);
fs.Close();
Console.WriteLine("Envelope Document {0} has been downloaded to:  {1}", i, filePath);
```

Comment: Can you give some examples of how email addresses are represented within the documents that you're downloading. (See also https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Check the `Content-Disposition` property in the response header, it has fileName.

Header in response will look like below:

```
Content-Disposition →file; filename="GettingStarted"; documentid="1"
```

It has fileName in the `Content-Disposition` value.